# A single procedure needed for every CLR-function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I'm just playing around a bit with CLR-Assemblies on a SQL2008 server. My first thought was: "Great, now I don't need to add 25 stored procedures and functions to get my main stored procedure readable. I just create one DLL and add all I need in it."

So I just tried a simple HelloWorld example from the MSDN and as an example how to call it I get:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hello
AS
EXTERNAL NAME HelloWorld.Procedures.HelloWorld
```

Is this the only way to call a function in a CLR-Assembly? I want to call it without creating a single stored procedure for every function in my class. Possible?

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but I am curious if I interpreted your question correctly in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, no! Every CLR stored procedure and stored function needs a T-SQL stored procedure or stored function defintion with the appropriate external name.

Comment: Well, not the answer I wanted to hear, but I guess it's the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no. It depends on exactly what you mean by "calling a function".

If you are speaking in terms of calling a method directly from T-SQL, then yes, every exposed method needs a T-SQL wrapper object to act as the bridge between the two (T-SQL and CLR). This interpretation of the question was made in the @Mithrandir's answer.

However, if you are speaking in terms of private / internal methods within your assembly, then no, those don't need the T-SQL wrapper objects. This interpretation is based on this statement:

> My first thought was: "Great, now I don't need to add 25 stored procedures and functions to get my main stored procedure readable. I just create one DLL and add all I need in it."

That statement implies that the desire is to have some internal methods that are called by the exposed method(s) so that you don't have so many calls cluttering up the main procedure. The exposed methods (i.e. the ones with the T-SQL wrapper objects) can share utility methods, and can even reference other assemblies, as long as those other assemblies are:

- in the same database, and
- have the same authorizing User

These utility methods can still do data access using the Context Connection, provided that they are called from methods that are exposed to T-SQL (i.e. have a `SqlFunction`, `SqlProcedure`, etc. attribute and a corresponding  T-SQL wrapper object).

You can even create an assembly that has no exposed methods, and contains only code referenced by your other assemblies. In this case, you have the option of using [ALTER ASSEMBLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186711.aspx) to set the `VISIBILITY` property to `OFF` (can't be done via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`). If you `DROP` an assembly that references another assembly that has its `VISIBILITY` set to `OFF`, then the non-visible assembly will be dropped automatically, just like a cascaded delete via a foreign key.